# Is there a way to distinguish between a case class and a Tuple?

Tags: scala

I wonder if there is a way to distinguish for implicit conversions without listing 22 options of `TupleN`?

```
implicit def forTuple[A <: Product](a:A) = createForTuple(a)
implicit def forCaseClass[A](a:A) = createForCaseClass(a)
```

The `forTuple` method is selected for case classes because they extend product as well.

Comment: Tuples are case classes, not sure how you can differentiate them without 22 explicit references.

Comment: Ahh, damn, yeah, I forgot that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with reflection as shown below (if you're using scala version 2.10):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def forEither[P <: Product : TypeTag](product: P) = {
  if (typeOf[P].typeSymbol.asClass.isCaseClass) forCaseClass(product)
  else forTuple(product)
}
```